# Can a triangle be constructed such that

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Can a triangle be constructed such that the cosines of its angles are $3/5, 5/13, 7/13$

There is no such triangle possible is the answer but how to prove it. Please help.

Comment: What is the property of three angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ which determines if they can be the angles of the same triangle or not?

Comment: Hint: the third angle is $\pi$ radians minus sum of the other two. Also, $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos(x)$

Comment: I got it, thank you.

Comment: Alternatively, an approach that the problem composer probably did **not** intend is that a pocket calculator's use of the Arccos function shows that the three angles are approximately $53.13^\circ, 67.38^\circ, 57.42^\circ.$